# How do I display a Vector3 to a Text Box?

Tags: vector, text, properties, coregames

I want to display a Vector3 onto a Text Box but I get an error. I print the Vector and it gave me x y and z. So this should be what's displayed to the Text Box, right? But I get an error. I do not understand what is wrong. Please help if you can, thanks!

```lua
local propTextLabel = script:GetCustomProperty("TextLabel"):WaitForObject()

local vector = Vector3.New(10,5,5)
print(vector) --> X=10.000 Y=5.000 Z=5.000
propTextLabel.text = vector --> Error: expected string, received Vector3: (bad argument into 'void(string)')
```

Answer (score 1):

`print()` accepts any object because the function automatically turns any object into its string representation. You'd have to convert objects into a string explicitly elsewhere:

```lua
propTextLabel.text = tostring(vector)
```